# Docusign connect X509

Tags: docusignapi

I would be interested by checking a request signature via the X509 certificate method (without SOAP), but after enabling the option in the connect config :

i don't find any signature into the request header or in some specific xml tag in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

An actual digital signature of the message is only available via SOAP.

Comment: Do you have an idea how do we do using rest api ?

Comment: You are referring to simple POST with XML payload?  There isn't a "payload signing" option for that.  Instead, we offer Mutual TLS as a way to ensure it is only DocuSign Connect that is trying to connect to your web app.  I understand that Basic Auth and some custom headers may be on the road map soon.